# Modifying an application with setup.exe without access to slice files

Tags: inno-setup

The disk spanning installer for our software has the option to download extra components from the web. For people to be able to download and install additional components after installing the software, I've added the `AppModifyPath` directive and copy the installer to the application path:

```
[Setup]
AppModifyPath="{srcexe}" /modify=1
...
[Files]
Source: "{srcexe}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

It turns out that the `setup.exe` requires the `setup-*.bin` files, which because of their size, I'd like to avoid copying into the application folder and don't really need as I only want to offer to add and remove downloadable components.

Is there a way to run the `setup.exe /modify=1` without needing access to the `setup-*.bin` data files, or create a separate executable that can be used to modify the original installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what @Slappy wrote.

Though indeed, you can create a *"separate executable that can be used to modify the original installation"*. Just implement another Inno Setup installer script with the same [`AppId`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) and install it along with your application.

---

Make sure the uninstaller of your modification installer is able to uninstall complete application. It should on its own. Just make sure you have no custom uninstall code there that would cause troubles.

Comment: This does work very nicely. I assumed using the same `AppId` would conflict. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Disk spanning and Data Download are two different features and they should not be mixed.

I recommend not to use Disk spanning if your setup is smaller than 2 GB (in that case Disk spanning is applied automatically) because there is no way doing that without access to the `setup-*.bin` data files.

Simply use the download feature directly: if some data are needed (e.g. if user check some checkbox) download data directly during the installation into `{app}` folder so you do not need any `setup-*.bin` data files..